# zeppelin notebook "error: not found: value %"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

according to [reading csv in zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966978/reading-csv-files-in-zeppelin-using-spark-csv) I should be using `%dep` to load the csv jar, but i get `error: not found: value %` anyone knows what i'm missing?

```
%spark

val a = 1

%dep
z.reset()
z.addRepo("Spark Packages Repo").url("http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven")
z.load("com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0")

a: Int = 1
<console>:28: error: not found: value %
              %dep
              ^
```

in `zeppelin` logs i see:

```
 INFO [2016-04-21 11:44:19,300] ({pool-2-thread-11} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:137) - Job remoteInterpretJob_1461228259278 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter1173192611
 INFO [2016-04-21 11:44:19,678] ({pool-2-thread-4} SchedulerFactory.java[jobStarted]:131) - Job remoteInterpretJob_1461228259678 started by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter1173192611
 INFO [2016-04-21 11:44:19,704] ({pool-2-thread-4} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:137) - Job remoteInterpretJob_1461228259678 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter1173192611
 INFO [2016-04-21 11:44:36,968] ({pool-2-thread-12} SchedulerFactory.java[jobStarted]:131) - Job remoteInterpretJob_1461228276968 started by scheduler 1367682354
 INFO [2016-04-21 11:44:36,969] ({pool-2-thread-12} RReplInterpreter.scala[liftedTree1$1]:41) - intrpreting %dep
z.reset()
z.addRepo("Spark Packages Repo").url("http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven")
z.load("com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0")
ERROR [2016-04-21 11:44:36,975] ({pool-2-thread-12} RClient.scala[eval]:79) - R Error .zreplout <- rzeppelin:::.z.valuate(.zreplin) <text>:1:1: unexpected input
1: %dep
    ^
 INFO [2016-04-21 11:44:36,978] ({pool-2-thread-12} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:137) - Job remoteInterpretJob_1461228276968 finished by scheduler 1367682354
 INFO [2016-04-21 11:45:22,157] ({pool-2-thread-8} SchedulerFactory.java[jobStarted]:131) - Job remoteInterpretJob_1461228322157 started by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter1173192611
```

Comment: This error is usually triggered if you don't use separate cells per interpreter.

Comment: According to docs, `%dep` interpreter should be used before `%spark`, `%pyspark`, `%sql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each cell can hold one type of interpreter. Thus is order to use `%dep` and `%spark` you should separate them into two cells starting with `%dep` after restarting the spark interpreter so it can be taken into consideration. e.g :

In the first cell :

```
%dep
z.reset()
z.addRepo("Spark Packages Repo").url("http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven")
z.load("com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0")
```

Now that your dependencies are loaded, you can access spark interpreter in a different cell:

```
%spark
val a = 1
```

**PS:** By default, a cell runs with the spark interpreter so you don't need to explicitly use `%spark`.